# Watch an object with numeric key in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, watch

Is there a way to watch a specific value within an object that has a numeric key with Vue2? If it was a "normal" string key such as `obj = {keyName: []}`, I know you can do this:

```
watch: {
   'obj.keyName'() {
      //Handle array change
   }
}
```

But what if I have an object like `obj = {1: []}` where the key is a number - I know you can't use the same watcher syntax with something like:

`'obj[1]'()`

and `obj.1` in normal code throws an error. Is there another way to set up a watcher for specifically that attribute of the `obj` object?

Comment: `'obj.1'(){ ... }` **will** work - try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this:

```js
watch: {
   'obj.1'() {
      // Handle array change
   }
}
```

The reason why this works is because `obj.1` isn't meant to be valid JavaScript code, instead Vue parses it and treats it as a simple keypath which is essentially equivalent to `obj['1']`.